# mounting an image and editing a configuring file ( within file system)using bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to mount an image file( .qcow2 file) and edit one of the files in file system with the following content :

```
address     192.168.xxx.xxx/24 active 
primary-dns   xx.x.64.20  
dns-domain    xxxx.xxtest  
static-route  xx1.xx.0/18 next-hop xxx.xxx.xxx.x  
li-local-save
```

i wrote the following automation code for mounting the .qcow2 file but not sure about editing the file with sed. please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir mntpt
modprobe nbd max_part=8
qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 $PWD/$1
mount /dev/nbd0p1 mntpt
sed -i "s/^\(address \).*/\1xxx.xxx.xxx/24 active/g" mntpt/bof.cfg
sed -i "s/^\(primary-dns \).*/\1x1.64.20/g" mntpt/bof.cfg
sed -i "s/^\(no \).*/\1li-local-save/g" mntpt/bof.cfg

qemu-nbd --disconnect /dev/nbd0
umount mntpt
```

Comment: What's the `\(no \)` for?  If you change `no food` to `no li-local-save` then that's fine, but your example doesn't agree with that hypothesis.  If you want to remove the `no` then omit the `\1` from the substitution part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing three separate sed scripts when one would do seems wasteful and potentially problematic. You separate commands with newline or (in some dialects) semicolon within a sed script.

Also, if the string needs to contain slashes, you either need to escape the slashes in the string, or use a different delimiter. You can use `s:foo:bar:` as a synonym of `s/foo/bar/` (with any nonalphabetic, nonnumeric character instead of the slash, really).

```
sed -i 's:^\(address \).*:\1xxx.xxx.xxx/24 active:
        s/^\(primary-dns \).*/\1x1.64.20/
        s/^\(no \).*/\1li-local-save/' mntpt/bof.cfg
```

(As far as I can tell, the `/g` flag you had is superfluous.  If you need to replace the same value multiple times *on the same line*, then add it back on.)

Comment: maybe a `[[:space:]]` instead of space char in your search pattern in case of a tab instead of several space char but it's a detail